# How to move grep inside awk script?

Tags: awk

In the below have I 3 `grep` commands that I would like to replace with awk's grep. so I have tried

```
! /000000000000/;
! /000000000000/ $0;
! /000000000000/ $3;
```

where I don't get an error, but testing with both the script below and

```
$ echo 000000000000 | awk '{ ! /000000000000/; print }'
000000000000
```

it doesn't skip the lines as expected.

**Question**

Can anyone explain why my "not grep" doesn't work in `awk`?

```
grep -v '^#' $hosts | grep -E '[0-9A-F]{12}\b' | grep -v 000000000000 | awk '{
    print "host "$5" {"
    print "  option host-name \""$5"\";"

    gsub(/..\B/,"&:", $3)
    print "  hardware ethernet "$3";"

    print "  fixed-address "$1";"
    print "}"
    print ""
}' > /etc/dhcp/reservations.conf
```

Comment: Do you want to print a line only if it doesn't match that pattern? If so, you need `! /blah/ { print }`. Note the pattern is *outside* the action block.

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting, you need NOT to use multiple `grep` with `awk`. Good that you showed your attempts in post. If you could simply post sample of input and sample of expected output then we could do it in single `awk` too.

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting, without seeing your `reservations.conf` file it is difficult to tell what is not working in addition to my previous comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try changing your code to:

```
echo 000000000000 | awk '!/000000000000/'
```

***Problem in your attempt:*** `$ echo 000000000000 | awk '{ ! /000000000000/; print }'` Since you are checking condition `! /000000000000/` which is having `;` after it so that condition works well and DO NOT print anything. But then you have `print` after it which is NOT COMING under that condition so it simply prints that line.

`awk` works on `pattern{action}` if you are putting semi colon in between it means that condition ends before it and statement after `;` is all together a new statements for `awk`.

---

---

***EDIT:*** Adding possible solution by seeing OP's attempt here, not tested at all since no samples are shown by OP. Also I am using `--re-interval` since my `awk` version is old you could remove in case you have new version of `awk` in your box.

```
awk --re-interval '!/^#/ && !/000000000000/ && /[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}/{
    print "host "$5" {"
    print "  option host-name \""$5"\";"
    gsub(/..\B/,"&:", $3)
    print "  hardware ethernet "$3";"
    print "  fixed-address "$1";"
    print "}"
    print ""
}' "$host" > /etc/dhcp/reservations.conf
```

Comment: I were clearly hoping that `awk` worked similar to `grep` by going to next input line, if the searhed didn't match. In regards to `pattern{action}` I did try `/something/ {next}` as this blog post shows. Why doesn't this work? https://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/skip-grep-use-awk/

Comment: @SandraSchlichting, so AFAIU your requirements, if you need NOT to print line which is having `000000000000` so either you could do `/000000000000/{next}` OR `!/000000000000/` both should work. But if you do `!/000000000000/{next}` this will print `000000000000` line, let me know if I made you my point clear here?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at your code:

```
$ echo 000000000000 | awk '
{ 
    ! /000000000000/ # on given input this evaluates to false 
                     # but since its in action, affects nothing
    print            # this prints the record regardless of whatever happened above
}'
```

Adding a `print` may help you understand:

```
$ echo 000000000000 | awk '{ print ! /000000000000/; print }'
0
000000000000
```

Removing the `!`:

```
$ echo 000000000000 | awk '{ print /000000000000/; print }'
1
000000000000
```

This is all I can help you with since there is not enough information for more.